# Why does deleting armature of model causes it to change size and orientation?

Tags: modeling, armature, mixamo

A character that I got from Mixamo, the Y-bot, gets deformed and scales into a very large model when I want to delete its armature. I want to transfer one animation from one model to this one by simply just aligning their armature. For some reason, when I try delete the Y-bot's armature, it gets deformed. Anyone wonder why? Is it because of modifiers or vertex groups (I never really understood vertex groups)?

[image: Image of me about to delete armature of character]

[image: What happens to character after armature is deleted]

Comment: Once it is not parented to the armature anymore, the mesh comes back to its default shape, maybe it's your problem here? Try to unparent Alt P > Clear and Keep Transformation, or please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/